# How to get the least cost element from an array in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have `item.warehouse_positions` array which has several prices and IDs, but I need to view only one `item.id` with lowest price. How can I do it?

```
<div v-for='(item, index) in item.warehouse_positions' :key='index'>
 {{ item.id }} -- {{ item.price }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
const lowestItem = item.warehouse_positions.sort((x, y) => x.price - y.price)[0];
```

Sort your objects by price and take out the first one, which should be the cheapest.

In Vue, your best bet is to make a computed property that returns this object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a computed property

```
computed:{
   getLowestItem(){
    return this.<YOUR_ARRAY_IN_DATA>.sort((a,b)=>a.price-b.price)[0]   
  }
}
```

Display it in  your template

```
<div>"{{getLowestItem}}"</div>
```